# Core Animation: Make content follow shadow path

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation, calayer

I have an animated shadow path of a CALayer:

```
CABasicAnimation* shadowAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"shadowPath"];
shadowAnimation.duration = duration;
shadowAnimation.timingFunction = function;
shadowAnimation.fromValue = (id) panelView.layer.shadowPath;

panelView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectSetOriginM20 (panelView.bounds, CGPointZero) cornerRadius: cornerRadius].CGPath;
[panelView.layer addAnimation: shadowAnimation forKey: @"shadow"];
panelView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
```

I need to recreate the same effect using an asset by settings the CALayer's content property to a UIImage. Is there a way to make the `bounds` follow the same animation as the shadow?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't make the content follow the shadow path.

Instead you have to animate the shadow path and the bounds together. This can be done in an animation group so that you only can configure the timing function and duration on the group.

```
CAAnimationGroup* shadowAndBounds = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
shadowAndBounds.duration = duration;
shadowAndBounds.timingFunction = function;

CABasicAnimation* shadowAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"shadowPath"];
// Set to and from value for the shadow path ...

CABasicAnimation* boundsAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"bounds"];
// Set to and from value for the bounds ...

shadowAndBounds.animations = @[ shadowAnimation, boundsAnimation ];
[panelView.layer addAnimation: shadowAndBounds forKey: @"shadowAndBounds"];
```